# How to show the selected radio button when the options are in an array?

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, radio-button

I want to return the contents of a folder as a radio button. I would like to be able to return the selected option in a variable so that I can then show the user what they have selected.

How do I solve this problem?

#### Attempt

```
$dir = '/beta/import/';
if ($dp = opendir($dir)) {
    $files = array();
    while (($file = readdir($dp)) !== false) {
        if (!is_dir($dir . $file)) {
            $files[] = $file;
        }
    }
    closedir($dp);
} else {
    exit('Directory not opened.');
}
if ($files) {
    echo ("<form action=\"#\" method=\"post\">");
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        echo '<input type="radio" name="files[]" value="' . $file . '" /> ' . $file . '<br />';
    }
    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />' . '</form>';
    echo "<br>";

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $selected_val = $_POST['$file'];
        echo "You have selected :" . $selected_val;
    }
} else {
    exit('No files found.');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use `name="files[]"`, `$_POST['files']` will be an array, not a single value. There's little point in doing this for radio buttons, since you can only select one of them, and the array will always have one entry. So you should change that to `name="file"`.

If you make that change, your code to print the selection should work.

You also need to remove `action="#"` from the form. That prevents the form from submitting, so you'll never get any `$_POST` variables (unless you submit the form using AJAX).

Comment: You, Sir, are a wonderful wonderful person! I was using action="#" as a test it will be replaced with another php page which will take the file name and doing something else.